# What's the difference between instance variable and temporary variable referenced in block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

[demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5KPs.png)

Like the screenshot describes.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by jam on 15/11/4.
//  Copyright © 2015年 Baidu Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CJTestObject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CJTestObject *testObject1;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _testObject1 = [[CJTestObject alloc] init];
    CJTestObject *testObject2 = [[CJTestObject alloc] init];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"_testObject1: %@", _testObject1);
        NSLog(@"testObject2: %@", testObject2);
    });
    _testObject1 = nil;
    testObject2 = nil;
}
@end
```

Console Output

```
2015-11-20 18:07:28.855 Test[33585:417965] _testObject1: (null)
2015-11-20 18:07:28.857 Test[33585:417965] testObject2: <CJTestObject: 0x79f564f0>
```

My question is what's the different between these two kinds variables **referenced in block**.

Comment: could you please copy the code from screenshot demo to the question? It would be more convenient:)

Comment: downvoted, please cooy the code AND make it a proper question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have this 2 variables of an object type, so your block should retain them in your case.

But the major difference here is that `testObject2` (Variable declared in the method scope) will be just retained, but when you capture `_testObject1` in block it retains `self` instead of an `_testObject1` (in your example). 
Capturing instance variable in block leads to retaining `self`, so block will keep the strong reference to `self` while this block exists.

When blocks are copied, any local object variables they refer to get automatically retained. They are then automatically released when the block is destroyed. This is convenient to ensure that the references remain valid. Any reference to `self` is a reference to a local object variable, causing `self` to be retained. Any reference to an instance variable is an implicit reference to `self` and causes the same thing.

You can find more details in this wonderful blog

https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html

UPDATE:
As for your console output, that what's happening when the block is getting executed:

```
NSLog(@"testObject1: %@", _testObject1);
```

Here it takes copied the reference to `self` and at the time of execution dereferences it's _testObject1 instance variable "pointer". In C it looks something like `self->_testObject1`.
You set the reference to _testObject1 to nil and after 2 seconds your block looks at this 'updated' reference.

```
NSLog(@"testObject2: %@", testObject2);
```

Here your block copied and retained reference to testObject2. When you set testObject2 = nil you set your variable's reference to nil. But block still has 'copied' and retained address to your variable, so it stores and prints that value.

It looks a bit complex but I hope it's possible to understand my answer :)

Comment: So, the key point is: when using `instance variables` in `block`, the `block` does not retain the `instance variables`, instead it retains the `instance`.